# Terraform prevent destruction of imported resources

Tags: terraform

I’ve stumbled across an issue in terraform and wonder if anyone knows a good way of working around this?

I’ve imported some pre-existing resources into terraform and then used these in my code. In the code I’ve defined the imported resources, `terraform apply`worked as expected. When I do `terraform destroy`, terraform now wants to destroy these resources. So I added a life cycle block with the `prevent_destroy=true` and now terraform destroy fails with the error below. From what I’ve seen on Github this issue has been around for a while, could anyone suggest a workaround?

> The plan would destroy this resource, but it currently has lifecycle.prevent_destroy set to true. To avoid this error and continue with the plan, either disable lifecycle.prevent_destroy or adjust the scope of the plan using the -target flag

Comment: importing these resources is most likely a mistake in this case, was there not a data resource that gave you the same data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the expected behavior. The message has the proper suggestion

> adjust the scope of the plan using the -target flag

In some case you do not need to import existing resource, as you can grab the needed info from the data sources of your provider.

Furthermore you can factor your imported resources in their own folder and "import" them as data source so they will not be part of the plan.